# How to shutdown when HDMI is unplugged?

Tags: scripts, hdmi

I use an old laptop as a media center PC. I want it to shutdown as soon as the TV is turned off, but only if it was connected before.
How do I do that?

Comment: I have heard of a monitor or a TV being used as a monitor able to shut down the computer. Does not sound like a good idea you could be doing something important on the computer and the TV goes off by accident.

Comment: Well, I'm not doing something important because it's just a media pc.
But there could be a 60s delay, which gives me time to interupt the shutdown.